# Time travel manga where the female protagonist travels back in time before her death, to prevent her harsh life ahead

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, sword-and-sorcery

It’s a story of a female protagonist who has a harsh life. Just as she is about to die, she time travels back into her young self. To avoid the future she already lived, she decides to gets strong by learning swordsmanship. After a while, she joins the army under the command of a prince who wears an eye patch. She is quite OP, and helps the prince.

It was kind of a medieval setting manga, with dukes and earls and count types. Time is when the use of sword and magic is prominent.

Comment: Do you know how long ago you read it? Do you know the time period it was set in? (I assume it was set in Japan), Feudal Japan (Time of the Samurai) More modern times? In some future setting?  I assume it was in English, was it published in English, or a web version some one had translated to English. Were you reading a Comic book, or was it a graphic novel, with multiple comic published in 1 volume.

Comment: Might also try googling "female time traveling swordsman manga" and search the images tab and see if you recognize anything.  Doing the same search in the "All" tab, I found this link. https://www.ranker.com/list/best-time-travel-manga/ranker-anime which may have it. You can try some of the other google links and see if you recognize anything.

Comment: it was kind of a medieval setting manga with dukes and earls and counts types. time is when the use of sword and magic is prominent.

Comment: @user135681 - If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. And if you found it useful, please [upvote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might be *[A Tale of the Secret Saint](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tensei-shita-daiseijo-wa-seijo-de-aru-koto-wo-hitakakusu)*.

[image]

> Fia always dreamed of becoming a knight. Born into a family of knights, she's the least talented among them, but she still clutches to her hope and trains with everything she has. When the day comes for her to slay a small demon and prove her worth, she ends up face to face with a dragon instead! A deadly injury makes her life flash before her eyes…and she suddenly remembers her former life, when she was a powerful Saint in a bygone era who defeated the Demon King. That life ended in pain because of who she was, making her fear ever becoming a Saint again. Now that the magic from her previous life has been rekindled, she may become a more powerful knight than she ever dreamed–if only she can survive long enough!

In a former life, the main character was a saintess with healing powers. She met her end at the hands of a demon, who promised he would find her after she was reincarnated as a saintess and kill her again.

She regains these memories and her saintess powers in her current life, but chooses to keep them a secret out of fear that the demon may make good on his promise. In her current life, she's an aspiring knight, and surreptitiously uses her powers to increase her speed and strength during sword fights. She also joins a knight order, headed by a knight commander who's a member of the royal family, and wears an eye patch.

(Note that she didn't actually go back in time. Her former life as a saintess happened 300 years prior to the main story, although she has the same physical appearance in both lives, and both time periods feature knights, saintesses, and monsters.)

[image]

[image]

[image]